# Тестирование метода Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, junit

Мне нужно протестировать метод, который посылает get запрос серверу, получает json-ответ и обрабатывает его.
Я только начал разбираться в spring и не могу понять, как настроить тест и замокать ответ сервера, потому что url сервера передаётся сразу в конструкторе:

```
@Component
public class ComponentApi {

private static final String URL = "URL";

public componentApi(ServiceRequestRepository serviceRequestRepository) {
    super(URL, serviceRequestRepository);
} 
public List<Warehouse> getWarehouses(Organization organization) {
     //тут выполняется get запрос к серверу
}
}
```

Контроллер:

```
@RestController
public class Controller {

private static final String URL = "URL";

@Autowired
private ComponentApi componentApi;

@RequestMapping(value = URL + "warehouses", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public List<Warehouse>  getWildberriesWarehouses(Organization organization) {
    return componentApi.getWarehouses(organization);
}
}
```

Я думаю, что надо тестировать метод компонента, пытался протестировать с помощью @RestClientTest, создать MockRestServiceServer и там указать локальный url и ответ, но всё валится с ошибкой. @SpringBootTest - как я понял, не подходит.
Можно ли как-то подменить ответ от сервера, который передаётся в конструкторе? Или подменить локальным "сервером"? Спасибо

Comment: Вам просто нужно в `ComponentApi` подложить мокнутый объект и этого будет достаточно. Посмотрите mockito.

Comment: Да, действительно, это оказалось проще, чем я думал.
Спасибо!